# Facing permission issue while copying tables schema from project-1 to project-2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

I have two GCP projects and the requirement is to copy a schema of 50 BQ tables from Project1 to Project2.

So far I tried to give service accounts of project1, access to project2.

For that I went to IAM&Admin and added the service account of project1 to the IAM&Admin of project2. And gave BQ Admin permission to the service account after adding under Project2

But still the issue persists.

Can anyone please let me know if there are other changes required ?

Comment: Can you please advise how you copy the table's schema from 1 project to the other and what is the error you are getting

Comment: Can you detail the command that you performed?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am using below command :

'bq query --use_legacy_sql=False  'create table `destination_project2.dataset2.table_1` AS select * from `source_project.dataset1.table_1` where 1=2'; '

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere This command I have written in a shell script and passing the  necesary arguments. Before running the script I gave the permissions to both service accounts   by adding these accounts in either of the projects IAM

Comment: Can you add to your question the results of this command: `gcloud config list`? Another thing, can you tell me if this query works : `select * from source_project.dataset1.table_1 where 1=2'`, and this command `bq ls --project_id=destination_project2 dataset2`? Finally, can you display the full error message? Thanks in advance